# Capturing Username out of OpenVPN logs using Regex

Tags: regex

I have the following Regex `('([a-z]+)'|\[([a-z]+)\])` that will capture the username joebloggs out of *both* of the following log lines generated by OpenVPN in pfSense.

- openvpn[18738]: 123.123.123.123:12345 [joebloggs] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]123.123.123.123:50453
- openvpn: user 'joebloggs' authenticated

The issue is in one case, it captures the square brackets and the other it captures the quotes.

Obviously this is sort of *by design* in order to capture the strings in both of the log formats, but ideally I would like to just capture the username, sans the dressing.

The log system capturing the pf logs is Graylog2 (which uses Java Regex matching) - the extractor will only capture the first Capture Group, hence why it is totally encapsulated inside one.

Comment: Try ``(?<=')[a-z]+(?=')|(?<=\[)[a-z]+(?=])`` or, if there must be a capturing group, ``((?<=')[a-z]+(?=')|(?<=\[)[a-z]+(?=]))``

Comment: That worked perfect Wiktor. I obviously need to look into lookaheads and lookbehinds!

If you post it as a proper answer, I'll give you credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<=')[a-z]+(?=')|(?<=\[)[a-z]+(?=])
```

Or, if there must be a capturing group, use

```
((?<=')[a-z]+(?=')|(?<=\[)[a-z]+(?=]))
```

**Details**

- `(?<=')[a-z]+(?=')` - 1+ lowercase ASCII letters immediately preceded and followed with `'` chars
- `|`  - or
- `(?<=\[)[a-z]+(?=])` - 1+ lowercase ASCII letters immediately preceded with `[` and followed with `]` chars.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!